# Flex sending snapshot without using base64Encode

Tags: apache-flex, image, actionscript, server-communication

```
var is:ImageSnapshot = myImagesnapshot;
var str:String = ImageSnapshot.encodeImageAsBase64(is);
```

As of now, I am sending my jpeg data to the server with the code above.
The problem is that it almost doubles the size of the data.
Is there a way to send the image data directly without using any encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of sending image data without using Base64 :

```
 var myEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
 var byteArray:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
 var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var url:String = "../../default.php";
    var saveJPG:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    saveJPG.requestHeaders.push(header);
    saveJPG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    saveJPG.data = byteArray;
```

On PHP side, I need to access :

```
 $globalS["HTTP_raw_post_data"]
```

Answer (score 1):

base64 increases size by a third, so if you really have about 100% overhead, you have a problem elsewhere.

haven't looked at the sources to well, but from the reference it seems, you could retrieve the [binary data directly](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html#data).

just tuck that into a [URLRequest](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data) and send it per [POST](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html#POST).

Answer (score -1):

You can save the snapshot as jpg or png.

Take a look at:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/07/using-the-imagesnapshot-class-to-capture-images-as-jpegs-or-pngs-in-flex-3/